# If a server handle request a thread pool, what's wrong when server need to serve lots of file?

Tags: multithreading, networking, network-programming

I am learning about network programming, and I have a question:

If a server using thread pool to handle the incoming request, we assumed that the thread pool has 128 available threads, a 1GB file must takes 10 minutes to write to client via HTTP, as the result, when a request ask for this 1GB file, and the thread which handle this request will be occupied.

My problem is if there are 129 requests ask for this 1GB files in the same time. All of threads will be occupied, and the 129th requests must wait one of request finish transferring. But it seems that most of HTTP servers such as Apache, Nginx, and so on, can handle lots of file serving in the same time. How do I improve the threadpool approach and make my server can handle more file serving in the same time?

Comment: You can handle multiple connections in each thread simultaneously. Implementation depends on language and platform you use. Keywords: "non-blocking IO", "select()", reactor pattern.

Comment: I am using epoll() but it handle reading data from socket, but writing data to socket can also handle with epoll/poll/select?

Comment: Yes, you can use single epoll() instance to do all four types of operations: read/write file/socket.